# Unmarshall DynamoDB JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

Given some **DynamoDB JSON** via a DynamoDB `NewImage` stream event, how do I unmarshall it to *regular JSON*?

```
{"updated_at":{"N":"146548182"},"uuid":{"S":"foo"},"status":{"S":"new"}}
```

Normally I would use [AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html), however I can't seem to find a generic Marshall/Unmarshall function.

Sidenote: Do I lose anything unmarshalling **DynamoDB JSON** to JSON and back again?

Comment: If others come looking for the python/boto version of this problem, here's the relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558646/how-to-convert-from-dynamodb-wire-protocol-to-native-python-object-manually-with

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall` function. Calling the following will return `{ updated_at: 146548182, uuid: 'foo', status: 'new' }`:

```
AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall({
    "updated_at":{"N":"146548182"},
    "uuid":{"S":"foo"},
    "status":{"S":"new"}
})
```

Everything that can be modeled in DynamoDB's marshalled JSON format can be safely translated to and from JS objects.

Comment: ARGH.. what an awful API that it requires that M thing `aws.DynamoDB.Converter.output({ 'M': record.dynamodb.NewImage })`

Comment: `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output` is the part of the DocumentClient that translates [DynamoDB AttributeValue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) objects to JSON-style objects. I assumed the `M` was part of the data you got in the stream event.

Comment: I opened a PR to improve the API by adding a `marshall` function that doesn't require the `M` key, and it was included in version 2.71.0 of the SDK.

Comment: Worked fine for me as of April 2020 using the AWS SDK Javascript API. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this is not working for me and it seems related to the fact that a query can return a mix of json that can be decorated or not with datatyping. For exemple this doesn't work : { "Items": [ { "entityType": { "S": "member" } } ], "Count": 1, "ScannedCount": 1 }... will result in : { Items: undefined, Count: undefined, ScannedCount: undefined } .. even array [] alone doesn't work.

Comment: Well... following my previous comment, I found in the doc API the AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient will do the appropriate unmarshalling. Here the complete doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property

Comment: @SteveS. The `unmarshall` function operates on string to [`AttributeValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) maps. AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient knows which fields in JSON responses returned by DynamoDB need to be unmarshalled. In the example you give above, every member of the `Items` array is unmarshalled by the DocumentClient.

Answer (score 48):

[AWS SDK for JavaScript version 3 (V3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/index.html) provides nice methods for [marshalling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#marshall-1) and [unmarshalling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#unmarshall-1) DynamoDB records reliably.

```
const { marshall, unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

const dynamo_json = { "updated_at": { "N": "146548182" }, "uuid": { "S": "foo" }, "status": { "S": "new" } };

const to_regular_json = unmarshall(dynamo_json);

const back_to_dynamo_json = marshall(to_regular_json);
```

Output:

```
// dynamo_json    
{ 
      updated_at: { N: '146548182' },
      uuid: { S: 'foo' },
      status: { S: 'new' }
}

// to_regular_json
{ updated_at: 146548182, uuid: 'foo', status: 'new' }

// back_to_dynamo_json
{
   updated_at: { N: '146548182' },
   uuid: { S: 'foo' },
   status: { S: 'new' }
}
```

Comment: For this to work for me in TypeScript, I had to cast unmarshall(recordImage as {
                        [key: string]: AttributeValue
                    });    // AttributeValue =  import { AttributeValue } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

Comment: Wow! You have NO IDEA how hard this is to find.. I don't see this documented much if at all or I am blind in the DynamoDB docs and this seems like a must have tool when working with it!